# VSFTPd 2.3.5 through iptables on Debian 7.6

Tags: debian, iptables, ftp, debian-wheezy

Configured and running vsftpd 2.3.5 on Debian 7.6 behind IPtables and fail2ban with ssl_enabled

I can't upload files properly because after a few I receive the following errors:

```
Timeout
or
OOPS: priv_sock_get_cmd
```

Here is a part of my vsftpd.conf

```
#passive mode
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=49192
pasv_max_port=50000

# Virtual Users Config
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=vsusers
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/vusers

strict_ssl_read_eof=YES
download_enable=NO
force_dot_files=YES#
```

followed by my iptable's rules (played a bit after some googling, dunno if they are proper)

```
# Allow FTP connections
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 20 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 49192:50000 -j ACCEPT
```

I found some posts talking about IPTABLES_MODULES="ip_conntrack_ftp" but there is no /etc/sysconfig on my system! Furthermore the following commands will error

```
sudo modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:554 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.2.41-042stab092.2/modules.dep.bin'

modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp
libkmod: ERROR ../libkmod/libkmod.c:554 kmod_search_moddep: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.2.41-042stab092.2/modules.dep.bin'
```

Any hints what to do?

EDIT: Transfers are working if I change ssl_enable=NO ... So is there a problem with SSL? Can't upload neither with FileZilla nor Cyberduck

EDIT2: debug_ssl throws the following error

```
DEBUG: Client "79.221.104.18", "SSL version: TLSv1/SSLv3, SSL cipher: AES256-SHA, reused, no cert"
DEBUG: Client "79.221.104.18", "SSL shutdown state is: SSL_RECEIVED_SHUTDOWN"
DEBUG: Client "79.221.104.18", "SSL shutdown state is: 3"
```

EDIT3: vsftpd ssl config

```
#SSL
ssl_enable=YES
allow_anon_ssl=YES
force_local_data_ssl=YES
force_local_logins_ssl=YES
force_anon_logins_ssl=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=YES
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
require_ssl_reuse=NO
```

EDIT4: It seems that something is wrong with the port handling? /proc/net/nf_conntrack reports the following dports where I specified 49192 to 50000

```
ipv4     2 tcp      6 111 TIME_WAIT src=**** dst=**** sport=50648 dport=49738 src=**** dst=**** sport=49738 dport=50648 [ASSURED] mark=0 secmark=0 use=2
ipv4     2 tcp      6 409189 ESTABLISHED src=**** dst=**** sport=49918 dport=21 [UNREPLIED] src=**** dst=**** sport=21 dport=49918 mark=0 secmark=0 use=2
ipv4     2 tcp      6 299 ESTABLISHED src=**** dst=**** sport=50756 dport=22 src=**** dst=**** sport=22 dport=50756 [ASSURED] mark=0 secmark=0 use=2
ipv4     2 tcp      6 409189 ESTABLISHED src=**** dst=**** sport=49899 dport=21 [UNREPLIED] src=**** dst=**** sport=21 dport=49899 mark=0 secmark=0 use=2
ipv4     2 tcp      6 409189 ESTABLISHED src=**** dst=**** sport=49916 dport=21 [UNREPLIED] src=**** dst=**** sport=21 dport=49916 mark=0 secmark=0 use=2
ipv4     2 tcp      6 118 TIME_WAIT src=**** dst=**** sport=50660 dport=49681 src=**** dst=**** sport=49681 dport=50660 [ASSURED] mark=0 secmark=0 use=2
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your kernel modules. You must solve your modprobe before solving your FTP problem. Do you compile your kernel ?

Comment: I am running Debian 7 mini-iso on an cheap VPS (openvz I think)... I installed iptables, fail2ban, db5.1-util, vsftpd, bash-completion, htop, nano, p7zip, wget by myself, nothing else so far. There seems to be a problem with SSL (please see my edit above) because I can upload files with ssl disabled

Comment: My provider stated nf_conntrack and nf_conntrack_ftp are active on my OpenVZ Container

Answer (score 0):

If the problem persists only when activating SSL,please try the following

```
 #SSL
 ssl_enable=YES
 allow_anon_ssl=NO
 force_local_data_ssl=YES
 force_local_logins_ssl=YES
 force_anon_logins_ssl=YES
 ssl_tlsv1=YES
 ssl_sslv2=NO
 ssl_sslv3=NO
 ssl_ciphers=HIGH
 require_ssl_reuse=NO
```

Otherwise set

```
 ssl_sslv2=YES    
 ssl_sslv3=YES
```

Comment: None of these two different configs worked here, still getting the same error. Doesn't matter whether all three or just two or just one at the time is being activated.

Comment: Fun fact: Working under Windows with FileZilla, same errors! I am very confused. Debian virtual machine throws error: SL ret: 18446744073709551615, SSL error: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno: 0 .... but still uploading. Theres a problem ... I will have users using mac, linux and windows. Needs to work properly :-( Same FileZilla config everywhere

Comment: you got any changes in your error, when you made changes in your ssl settings as suggested ?

Comment: Yes, small changes. **Windows:** `SSL cipher: AES256-GCM-SHA384` --- 
**Linux:** `"SSL ret: 18446744073709551615, SSL error: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno: 0" , FAIL UPLOAD file , Connection terminateded without SSL shutdown - buggy client? , 3times SSL_SENT_SHUTDOWN , SSL cipher: AES128-SHA`

Comment: **EDIT:** turning on tcp_wrappers didn't help (wanted to try that), disabling connect_from_port_20 either... running out of ideas

Comment: Maybe I have to explain my problem again... The upload per se is working. I can see the progress (atleast within filezilla) but after 5 uploads I will get an connection timeout. FileZilla then reconnects and tries to upload the same files again. The STOR is not being handled properly with SSL. **Error for example:** `STOR TeX-Example.zip > Upload > Connection Timeout > File transfer failed after sending 959319 Bytes in 25 seconds > Reconnect`